# Pass 2 arguments from subform to another form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a main form called frmGeneralInformation with a subform frmRetroVerso.

The form frmRetroVerso has 2 fields: SurveyID and FolioNo and 2 buttons: Retro and Verso.

The Retro button opens the form of frmFolioRetro.

I would like frmFolioRetro gets the arguments SurveyID and FolioNo from frmRetroVerso and either shows the record or else lets me input the details for the new record. Somehow SurveyID and FolioNo are not being updated according to the arguments sent. Can someone help pls?

This is the code I have in the subform frmRetroVerso:

```
Private Sub Verso_Click()
Const FORMNAME = "frmFolioVerso"
Const MESSAGETEXT = "No current folio number."
    ' be sure a record has been entered
    If Not IsNull(Me.FolioNo) And Not IsNull(Me.SurveyID) Then
        ' save current client record
        Me.Dirty = False
    
        ' open linked form in dialogue mode
        DoCmd.OpenForm FORMNAME, _
            WhereCondition:=Me.FolioNo & " AND " & Me.SurveyID, _
            OpenArgs:=(Me.FolioNo & ";" & Me.SurveyID)
    Else
         MsgBox MESSAGETEXT, vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Retro_Click()

Const FORMNAME = "frmFolioRetro"
    Const MESSAGETEXT = "No current folio number."
    
    ' be sure a record has been entered
    If Not IsNull(Me.FolioNo) And Not IsNull(Me.SurveyID) Then
        ' save current client record
        Me.Dirty = False
        ' open linked form in dialogue mode
        DoCmd.OpenForm FORMNAME, _
            WhereCondition:=Me.FolioNo & " AND " & Me.SurveyID, _
            OpenArgs:=(Me.FolioNo & ";" & Me.SurveyID)
    Else
         MsgBox MESSAGETEXT, vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation"
    End If

End Sub
```

and this is the code I have in frmFolioRetro which should be almost the same as frmFolioVerso:

```
Private Sub SurveyID_GotFocus()
    On Error Resume Next
    Forms("frmRetroVerso").Dirty = False
    Me.SurveyID.DefaultValue = """" & Forms("frmRetroVerso").SurveyID & """"
End Sub

Private Sub FolioNo_GotFocus()
    On Error Resume Next
    Forms("frmRetroVerso").Dirty = False
    Me.FolioNo.DefaultValue = """" & Forms("frmRetroVerso").FolioNo & """"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()

    If IsNull(Forms("frmGeneralInformation").SurveyID) Then
        Me.AllowAdditions = False
    Else
        Forms("frmGeneralInformation").Dirty = False
        Me.AllowAdditions = True
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
    
        Dim value1 As String
        Dim value2 As String
        
        value1 = Split(Me.OpenArgs, ";")(0)
        value2 = Split(Me.OpenArgs, ";")(1)
        Me.SurveyID.DefaultValue = """" & value2 & """"
        Me.FolioNo.DefaultValue = """" & value1 & """"
        MsgBox (Me.SurveyID.DefaultValue)
        MsgBox (Me.FolioNo.DefaultValue)
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are users supposed to be able to edit the FolioNo and UserID fields on these two forms?

Comment: Have you step debugged? I tested code setting DefaultValue with GotFocus event and it works, although both values won't appear until another control gets focus. Why bother with GotFocus for this when Open event sets DefaultValue?

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE CONDITION is incomplete. Need to reference fields on forms that parameters should apply to. If those fields are named FolioNo and SurveyID and are number type:

`WhereCondition:="FolioNo=" & Me.FolioNo & " AND SurveyID=" & Me.SurveyID,`

Answer (score 0):

If  your where clause is correct, then ONLY records that match the where clause will show, and I don't see the need to "pass" the values to the form - it will filter to the records you asked.

Now, it is possible perhaps that the record does not exist. But then I would write code to check that, add the record BEFORE you launch that form. And thus once again the two values are now available in that target form as text boxes with values.

If for some strange reason you DO need the two values passed in addition to the filter that should already do what you want?

Then in the target form simply declare two variables at the form's code module level (at the start before any code say like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public MyFoioNum    As Long
Public MySurvayID   As Long
```

So, now in your code you can go:

```
code to open the form with filter as you have
dim strF      as string
strF = "name of form to open"
DoCmd.OpenForm strF, _
        WhereCondition:=Me.FolioNo & " AND " & Me.SurveyID, _
        OpenArgs:=(Me.FolioNo & ";" & Me.SurveyID)
forms(strF).MyFoioNum = me.FoiliNo
forms(strF).MySurvayID = me.SurveyID
```

So, the above would now allow any VBA code in that form to freely use MyFoioNo, and MySurvaryID. But AS NOTED, since you filtering the form by these two numbers, then I see VERY little reason to pass the two values.

As noted, if the target form record MIGHT not exist? Then write code to check if target record exits, and if not add in it code and THEN RUN the same code you have now to open the form with the filter. (so it will always work since it (you the developer) ALWAYS assume the target record will exist based on the filter).

So it somewhat easier to check for the record BEFORE you launch that form, if not add it, and THEN launch the form.

I suppose you could try and place the code in the target form startup to check for the record, and if not add it (but the form will have a filter already set). So, it is somewhat easier to do this before you launch the form.
So, you trade off having to setup the ability to pass two values and set them from the calling code, or simply have the calling code add the reocrd. That way, the calling form does not care nor need the two values passed - but just a filter, and thus any code in the system can freely call that form without having to pass values.
You adopt the code rule that the filter you send ALSO assumes that the target form and record already exists.

Note that this suggestion to "set" values after the form been loaded as per above? This will of course only work for a model form, or a popup form (which is your case!). For a form opened as dialog, then calling code will halt, and wait until such time the user closes the form for the calling code to continue.

So, you can pass 1, 2 or 5 values using the above idea of creating public variables in the target form, then open it via calling code, and the calling code is thus free to set those public values right after the form is opened.